# IEnumerable of Tuple of string of string

Tags: c#

I have `IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>>` data as a parameter in a method and 
 I'm struggling to populate / pass the data from the caller .

Comment: What kind of data do you already have, and what kind of data does it expect?

Comment: @Rup `Tuple.Create` is more ergonomic as it doesn't require type-parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a list of a POCO (or some other object) with two string properties that you want to pass in...

```
List<MyObject> list = ...

IEnumerable<Tuple<String,String>> enumerableTuples = list
    .Select( o => Tuple.Create( o.StringProperty1, o.StringProperty2 ) );

SomeMethod( enumerableTuples );
```

If you have a `List<String[]>` then it's similar:

```
List<String[]> list = ...

IEnumerable<Tuple<String,String>> enumerableTuples = list
    .Select( arr => Tuple.Create( arr[0], arr[1] ) );

SomeMethod( enumerableTuples );
```

If you have a `List<(String,String)>` (`ValueTuple`) then use the `.ToTuple()` method:

```
List<(String,String)> list = ...

IEnumerable<Tuple<String,String>> enumerableTuples = list
    .Select( t => t.ToTuple() );

SomeMethod( enumerableTuples );
```

Comment: ValueTuple for the win

Comment: @TheGeneral Unfortunately the OP says they're using the older reference-type `System.Tuple<T1,T2>` rather than the sexy new `ValueTuple<T1,T2>` - at least it isn't a C# Anonymous Type.